# Redirection of stdin and stdout via pipes in C works for external programmes but not for recursive call

Tags: c, recursion, pipe, fork, io-redirection

I am trying to communicate with forked child processes via pipe redirection of stdin and stdout in C. I already managed to get this to work for shell commands (like `ls`, for example) executed in child processes. However, I wasn't able to recursively execute the same program and redirect the output (printed by `printf()`, `fprintf()` to `stdout`, ...) via the pipes from the child process to the parent (in this test to `stdout` of the parent), although this works fine for `ls` or similar commands.

Here's how I tried to approach this:

- I create a pipe, the reading end is for the parent, the child process should write to the writing end.
- The Process forks, both processes close the unused end, respectively.
- The writing end of the pipe is redirected to `STDOUT_FILENO` and closed
- The child process executes the program recursively (it is called ./to2)

As mentioned, this does work if I execute `ls` in the child process, but not if I try to call the same program recursively. Here's my test program where I tried to get this to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


static void usage(void){
    fprintf(stderr,"RIP");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    if(argc > 1){
        dprintf(STDOUT_FILENO,"Please work\n"); 
        printf("\n THIS IS A MESSAGE FROM THE CHILD \n");
        fputs("Pretty Please!\n",stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    int p1[2];
    if(-1 == pipe(p1)) { 
        fprintf(stderr,"pipe\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",strerror(errno));
        usage();    
    }
    int f = fork();
    if(f == 0){
        close(p1[0]);
        if(dup2(p1[1],STDOUT_FILENO) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr,"dup2\n");
            usage();
        }
        close(p1[1]);

        //I want this to work:
        //execlp("./to2", "./to2", "-e");

        //This works fine:
        execlp("ls", "ls");

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else if (f == -1) {
        usage();
    } else  {
        close(p1[1]);
        int w = -1;
        if(-1 == wait(&w)) usage();
        char b[12];
        memset(b,0,12); 
        read(p1[0],&b,12);

        char reading_buf[1];

        while(read(p1[0], reading_buf, 1) > 0){ 
            write(1, reading_buf, STDOUT_FILENO);
        }
        close(p1[0]);
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, the function is called recursively with additional arguments, while the parent program is called without additional arguments (hence the `if(argc>1)`).
In the final program, endless recursion is being avoided by other means.

Did I understand something wrongly? I am pretty confused by the fact that the only thing that doesn't seem to work is redirecting the output of my *own*
program...

Thank you very much in advance, any help or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  When you're showing us code, you should aim to show an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You have quite a lot of headers in your code that aren't in use — `<signal.h>`, `<sys/netdb.h>`, `<sys/socket.h>`, `<time.h>`, `<fcntl.h>`, `<sys/stat.h>` I believe are unused, and `<sys/types.h>` isn't really needed in modern POSIX (since 2004, IIRC), though the Linux man pages still tend to list it. Do make sure your error messages end with a newline; it improves readability. It's unusual to exit with `EXIT_SUCCESS` when the `execlp()` has failed.

Comment: You talk about recursion, but there are only two functions shown — `main()` and `usage()`.  I see no recursive call to `main()` and `usage()` is certainly not recursive, so it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: You say `//This works fine:` followed by a broken `execlp("ls", "ls");` — that should not work because you've not provided a null pointer to mark the end of the argument list (`execlp("ls", "ls", (char *)0);` would be correct).  It might happen to work by chance, but it most certainly isn't correct.  You are correct that you don't need to test the return value from `execlp()` — it never returns on success and only returns on failure to execute the specified the child program.

Comment: The null pointer missing might well be why you have problems when the program is written to run itself again.  This is not what is normally meant by 'recursion', though.  Normally, recursion refers to a function calling itself, directly or indirectly, within a single process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary problem is precisely as outlined in the comments — you are not calling [`execlp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execlp.html) correctly (nor `ls` in the alternative).  You must make the last argument on those function calls into an explicit null pointer, as shown in this code, which is a mostly mildly edited version of what's in the question:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void usage(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "RIP\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        dprintf(STDOUT_FILENO, "Please work\n");
        printf("THIS IS A MESSAGE FROM THE CHILD\n");
        fputs("Pretty Please!\n", stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    int p1[2];
    if (-1 == pipe(p1))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pipe: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        usage();
    }
    int f = fork();
    if (f == 0)
    {
        close(p1[0]);
        if (dup2(p1[1], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "dup2: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            usage();
        }
        close(p1[1]);
        execlp(argv[0], argv[0], "-e", (char *)0);
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to exec %s again\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (f == -1)
    {
        usage();
    }
    else
    {
        close(p1[1]);
        char b[13];
        memset(b, 0, 13);
        if (read(p1[0], &b, 12) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read from pipe (%s)\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        int len = strcspn(b, "\n");
        printf("M1 [%.*s]\n", len, b);

        char reading_buf[1];

        while (read(p1[0], reading_buf, 1) > 0)
        {
            write(1, reading_buf, STDOUT_FILENO);
        }
        close(p1[0]);
        int w = -1;
        if (-1 == wait(&w))
            usage();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Two important changes should be highlighted:

- This code echoes the first line of data — the one written by `dprintf()` — whereas the original code just read it and discarded it.
- The `wait()` call is after the input, not before.  If the child had more data to write than a set of fixed messages, it could block waiting for the parent to read some of the data, while the parent is blocked waiting for the child to exit.  This would be a deadlock.

The `usage()` function is not appropriately named — it doesn't report how to run the program.  I also exit with a failure status, not success, if the child process fails the `execlp()`.

Under peculiar circumstances, the `wait()` call might report on the exit status from some child other than the one that was forked.  It is generally best to use a loop to reap such children.  However, the circumstances required are extremely peculiar — the process which launched the parent with an `exec*()` function must have previously created some children for which it didn't wait, so that they are inherited by the parent process (because the PID doesn't change across an `exec*()` call).

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly my problem. Since `ls` seemed to work seemlessly with and without NULL termination, I didn't consider this to be my problem. Also thanks for your further remarks, I really appreciate the feedback.